# How to develop a package in R?

Tags: r, package, r-s4

I have written some functions in `R` using S4 classes.

Now I want to build an `R` package out of these functions.

How should I proceed?  Is there anything that I should do differently because I have used S4 classes?

Comment: @Roman nice way to hide that behind a tinyurl wrapper so SO didn't obliterate it :-)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Consult the following reference material:

1. Chapter 1, [Creating R packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Creating-R-packages), of the [Writing R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) manual.  This is the canonical source.  It's the ultimate reference point, but not necessarily the best starting point.
2. A [short presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/hadley/r-packages) outlining the key ideas in package development and using the [devtools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) package for development
3. Hadley's [devtools wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki), particular the [Package basics](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Package-basics) section.
4. The R help for `?package.skeleton` and `?create` in `devtools`.
5. The [presentation by Uwe Ligges](http://user2010.org/tutorials/Ligges.pdf) at `useR!2010` on package development.
6. [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) by Hadley Wickham.

Comment: Instead of `package.skeleton`, I recommend `create` in the `devtools` package. Does a better job...