# Simple and easy steps to make R package?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop a package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297458/how-to-develop-a-package-in-r)

I read some material about making R package and get confuse.
Could any one illustrate simple and easy steps of making R package on windows for both operating system(windows and linux) with C++ code file?
Thanks

Comment: IMO this would be more appropriate for SO, but it would help to clarify your goals before it gets migrated anywhere. Have you read this thread on the site, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5418/1036?

Comment: Would it be possible to know where this thread was duplicated so we could examine the answers there and further respond to the poster if further assistance is needed?

Comment: I am looking for summarize steps to make R package. I have already google stuff, but not able understand.

Comment: I read your question about package and get confuse.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to have a look at Hadley Wickham recomendations:

[Hadley Wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki)

[Hadley Package basics](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Package-basics)