# Execute a function from package after doing library(pkg)

Tags: r, function, load, package

Hi I have a package with a functions that makes a gui with gWidgets, is there a way I can get this to be executed on package load so the interface comes up straight away.

I thought something like this:

```
.OnAttach <- function(libname, pkgname){
  gui()
}
```

would work, but I'm still learning about hooks, and the events during package load and unload, and R environment stuff.

EDIT:

This is what I currently have in my zzz file:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname = find.package("GspeEaR"), pkgname = "GspeEaR") {
  gui()
}
```

Thanks,

Ben W.

Comment: have you checked out `.onLoad` you dump it in a .R file called zzz traditionally.  Here's an example where I've used this: https://github.com/trinker/gmailR/blob/master/R/zzz.R

Comment: @TylerRinker, why don't you make this an answer?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want `.onLoad` which you dump in a .R file called zzz.R (traditionally). Here's an example where I've used this: [github.com/trinker/gmailR/blob/master/R/zzz.R](http://github.com/trinker/gmailR/blob/master/R/zzz.R)

Comment: I've just tried this, I'll have to try it on my PC later because I'm not sure if this is solely due to my being on a mac at work, but when I build and reload in RStudio:Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'GspeEaR', details:
  call: function (classes, fdef, mtable) 
  error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘.gwindow’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
Error: loading failed

Comment: Just tried on my PC, same error happens. The error is beyond my deciphering abilities, I've updated my question show show what I currently have in my zzz file.

Comment: @TylerRikner why do you define the `.onload` in this way? I mean why are initializing parameters ? I have used your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045999/how-to-check-platform-in-onload-in-the-r-package/26046264?noredirect=1#comment40904153_26046264) but it looks wrong.(see hadley comment below my answer in the mentioned link)

Comment: Not sure.  I'd like to see Hadley expand on how `.onload` does work.  PS I no long use this method in that package as you can click the link and see.  Here's a bit on it here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-dirty-hack-for-importing-packages-that-use-depends/  And this is where my introduction to `.onLoad` first began: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10508191/1000343  But I don't really use it so am likely misunderstanding it.

Comment: @TylerRinker thanks. I just update my answer in the other question. Thanks again for your feedback.