# Extended R package can't correctly communicate with its 'parent' R package

Tags: r

I am trying to build a package that extends another package. However at its most basic level I am doing something wrong. I build a simple example that presents the same issue:

I have two packages, `packageA` and `packageB`. `packageA` has a single R file in the R folder that reads:

```
local.env.A <- new.env()

setVal <- function()
{
  local.env.A$test <- 1
}

getVal <- function()
{
  if(!exists("test", envir = local.env.A)) stop("test does not exist")
  return(local.env.A$test)
}
```

For packageB I have the following single R file in the R folder:

```
# refers to package A
setVal()

getValinA <- function()
{
  return(getVal())
}
```

I want both `packageA` and `packageB` to be available for end users, therefore I set packageB to depend on `packageA` (in the description file). When `packageB` is loaded, e.g. by means of `library(packageB)` I expect it to run `setVal()` and thus set the test value. However, if I next try to get the value that was set by means of `getValinA()`, it throws me the stop:

```
> library(packageB)
Loading required package: PackageA
> getValinA()
Error in getVal() : test does not exist
```

I am pretty sure it is related to environments, but I am not sure how. Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14926672/1412059

Comment: @Roland That indeed did the trick. I was not aware of the .onLoad function.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer your question with what you have learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to @Roland. The answer was very simple. I was under the impression (assumptions assumptions assumptions!) that when you perform `library(packageB)` it would load all the actions within it, in my case perform the `setVal()` function. This is however not the case. If you wish this function to be performed you need to place this within the function .onLoad:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname)
{
  setVal()
}
```

By convention you place this `.onload` function in an R file called `zzz.R`. Reason being that if you do not specifically collate your R scripts it will load alphabetically, and it makes sense to perform your actions when at least all the functions in your package are loaded.